# Attribute fields vs. attribute-value map

Tags: java, optimization, coding-style

I have a (java) class with about 10 attributes, many of them potentially staying **uninitialized** and are **not accessed** during lifetime of an object.

Therefore I'm considering using a `Map<String,Object>` as an attribute-name -> attribute-value map instead of a lot of fields, in order to save resources.
Now I am wondering, if there exist any offical or unofficial rules, when and how to decide on one of the described possibilities. How many attributes should a class have, before I should consider using such a map? Should I use it at all?

Thanks in advance for your advice/opinions on that.

Comment: JVM is performing waaaay more smarter optimizations than you can imagine. So no, you don't need it.

Comment: So you mean, if my idea is saving resources, then the JVM will probably optimize it just as well? Yes, that sounds reasonable, thanks! :-)

Comment: @Murat What you're claiming there seems pretty complicated to implement and involves at least one additional indirection and some overhead. Also I'm not aware of any JVM (even academic ones) that have implemented this. So please post some links.. Now obviously the worst thing an uninitialized variable in Java can take up is 8 byte so we're saving at best `80 bytes - overhead of a map` which means that solution is probably worse from a memory pov, but still..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so you're doing this to save memory I assume because clearly you're not saving CPU resources by accessing a map instead of a field. So let's see how good that works out: (assuming 64bit JVM without compressed oops - which is unrealistically but shouldn't change the results too much, you can compute it yourself easily)

Basically a field in java will never take up more than 8bytes (well word size for references). So this means for your class with 10 fields, assuming all are unused the best we can save are 8*10 bytes = 80byte.

Now you want to replace this with one HashMap instead - that means we already use up 8 extra bytes for that. Also the HashMap is always initialized so we get the overhead of: 2 words header + reference + 3 ints + float + 1 array (2 words overhead, 4byte size, 16 references by default) which takes up `182 bytes` of memory.

May I congratulate you to saving a whopping `-110 bytes`!

PS: I think the smallest possible default value for the backing array of the hashset is 2, so you could use that and come out about even. But as soon as you store objects in the set, you get additional overhead from the Wrapper objects used by the class. So really it's a bad idea.

Comment: Interesting to see the mathematical argument, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

It's not about how many different attributes you have it's about how they are used and what is needed. A `Map` will allow for more flexibility to not have attributes or to have different attributes for different instances or add attributes later (through adding things to the `Map`). But if the attributes are different types `String, Integer, Doubles` etc this will require making the `Map` of type `Object` and casting all the values when you use them (a lot more work for you).

Comment: So, for the casting problem I would write getter methods to do the job (but of course, all attributes have to be known before compile time for this to work). Anyway I get your point: An attribute-value map only makes sense, if you need your attributes to be 'flexible' as described by you. I doesn't seem to make sense in the scenario, I want to use it. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Map is a good idea.

- from OO point of view, fields are properties of a Type and its subType. think about inheritance and polymorphism, how can you make the Map achieve those characters of OO?
- even if talking about code style, this is not making your codes cleaner. How do you handle type casting? exception handling? those codes would be much more than the field declaration and getter/setters (if you have them)

Comment: The fields are all `private`, so there wouldn't be problems with inheritance, I think, but I agree, that the map construction does not seem to be 'natural'. And yes, the getters and setters code is uglier compared to using simple field getters/setters.

Answer (score 0):

I like the Map idea for attributes which are truly optional and "non-essential".  Otherwise you'll need a whole bunch of subclasses and/or you always need to check for null in your getters.

As for the typing, I often write code passing in the default value as the 2nd argument, and use it to determine the return type.  e.g.

```
  int getValue(String key, int defaultValue);
  double getValue(String key, double defaultValue);
  String getValue(String key, String defaultValue);
```

The caller, not the Map, has to know the type.  YMMV whether you like this style...

However, for attributes which are "essential", I prefer real fields.